# What is the "path" parameter in the GET method of the R httr package for?

Tags: r, httr

In the documentation at:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf, it only says that:

```
Further parameters, such as query, path, etc, passed on to modify_url. These parameters must be named.
```

Then in the section for modify_url, it says:

```
components of the url to change
```

There is also an example:

```
# You might want to manually specify the handle so you can have multiple
# independent logins to the same website.
google <- handle("http://google.com")
GET(handle = google, path = "/")
GET(handle = google, path = "search")
```

But (like many examples in R documentation, LOL!), the example didn't say much about the difference between using `path = "/"` vs `path = "search"`.

So, what is `path` for?

Comment: It's the "part" part of a URL is the part after the host name including the "folders" and "page name." So the first example accesses the main page of google `http://google.com/` while the second accesses the main search page `http://google.com/search` (in this case they end up going to the same place). But if you wanted a particular page, say "new.html", it would go in the path of the URL.